# To use data from an XML using actionscript 3 to manipulate a movieclip

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

creating a clock system, need to access data from xml. The elements within the data determines the colour of he building. Need help to link the data within the xml with the object in the interface and to position them. so far i've been able to extract the data but dont know how to link those two to position them. i've only come up to this far.

```
import com.greensock.loading.*;
import com.greensock.loading.display.*;
import com.greensock.events.LoaderEvent;
import flash.events.Event; 
import flash.net.URLLoader; 


var xmlLoader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML);

var xmlData:XMLList=new XMLList();
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("xmldata.xml"));

function loadXML(e:Event):void
{
    var i:int;
    xmlData = new XMLList(e.target.data);
    var theDots = xmlData.dots;
    var posx = xmlData.dots.posx;
    var posy = xmlData.dots.posy;
    for ( i=0; i<theDots.length(); i++ )
    {
        var dot_name = theDots[i].name;
        var pos_x = theDots[i].posx;
        var pos_y = theDots[i].posy;

        var mc:MovieClip = new theDot;
        var pos_x:Point X = new x;
        var pos_y:Point Y = new y;  
    }

}
```

Comment: I think we need a little more to go on here, what does the xml look like, and what does the interface look like?

Comment: sorry, though something was missing. its a short version of the xml but the elements are only these.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?> 
<data>
 <dots>
  <name>Press</name>
  <ip>1.1.1</ip>
  <posx>-146.3</posx>
  <posy>18.1</posy>
 </dots>
 <dots>
  <name>Body</name>
  <ip>1.1.2</ip>
  <posx>-146.3</posx>
  <posy>18.1</posy>
 </dots>
 <dots>
  <name>Body 2</name>
  <ip>1.1.3</ip>
  <posx>-146.3</posx>
  <posy>18.1</posy>
 </dots> 
 <dots>
  <name>CKD</name>
  <ip>1.1.4</ip>
  <posx>-146.3</posx>
  <posy>18.1</posy>
 </dots>
</data>

Answer (score 0):

You have to design your `TheDot` class and all the other simple classes to accept properties in the constructor, probably with default values, or give them function(s) to accept properties, probably in bulk, as say coloring a building will initiate a graphics recreation. An example:

```
public class TheHouse extends Sprite {
    private var fillColor:uint; // with alpha
    private var lineColor:uint;
    private var lineThickness:Number;
    private function drawHouse():void {
        // drawing house
        this.graphics.clear();
        this.graphics.lineStyle(lineThickness,(lineColor & 0xffffff),
            Number(lineColor>>>24)/255); // alpha is 0..1
        this.graphics.beginFill((fillColor&0xffffff),
            Number(fillColor>>>24)/255);
        this.graphics.circle(0,0,20); // *le perfectly drawn house code
        // actually here go graphics commands to draw a house via lines/curves
        this.graphics.endFill();
    }
    public function TheHouse() {
        lineColor=0xff000000;
        fillColor=0xffffffff;
        lineThickness=1.0;
        drawHouse();
    }
    public function set outlineColor(value:uint):void {
        if (lineColor==value) return;
        lineColor=value;
        drawHouse();
    } 
    // similarly do other setters
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks! it helped me a lot. ddnt know that you could that with graphics, i set the graphic as a movieclip so i just replace those in right? again, many thanks. :)

Comment: You can create a custom class that only contains code, and then you extend anything you want and do anything with its graphics. Of course,  this requires lots of code to draw a picture with only `moveTo()` and `curveTo()` or `lineTo()` and fills. But, you can attempt to call `graphics.readGraphicsData()` on an existing MovieClip and examine that, so you will be able to reproduce your hand-drawn stuff while changing only color or thickness.